# How to know how to set uvicorn parameters given kubernetes resource limitations

Tags: python, kubernetes, uvicorn

I have a kubernetes cluster that, let's say, has a given resource limitation:

```
                            request_cpu: "1000m",
                            request_mem: "1Gi",
                            limit_cpu  : "4000m",
                            limit_mem  : "3Gi",
                            replicas   : "3"
```

On that cluster I would like to run an uvicorn web server (and python application in it).
How to know the best configuration parameters for the uvicorn?

At the moment I tried several combinations with various values for the number of workers and limit_concurrency. Like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("start:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=8080, reload=True, workers=4, limit_concurrency=20)
```

Is it generally true that the limit_concurrency should be very high? How would this setting influence the python application that takes 10s to complete when single request is posted?

Comment: Do you use uvicorn now? Can you share your experience?

Comment: hi @FranklinPiat, yes. But for for deployment on k8 we use gunicorn with uvicorn workers. It is tricky to get intuition how scaling combination works on k8 when a web server is deployed in a container. The latest finding that I have is to set the limit and request parameters of the k8 yaml to the same value - this fix prevent some uncontrolled resource usage when there is a larger number of applications, containers, and web servers are deployed on the same k8 cluster.